# How to identify checkbox element nested within multiple span element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to identify the checkbox element which has been nested within multiple span element, below is my code snippet

```
<asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chk1" CssClass="required" Style="vertical-align : baseline ; margin:0px;" >
   <span style="background : none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0% ; cursor: pointer ; display : inline-block ; margin-right : 8px ; text-align : right ; vertical-align : top ; width : 160px">
                            HI HOW ARE YOU...</span>

<span style="cursor : pointer ; font : 99% sans-serif ; height : 27px ; margin : 0px ; padding-bottom : 0px ; padding-left : 8px ; padding-right : 10px ; padding-top : 7px ; text-align : left ; vertical-align : top ; width : 257px">
<span style="display:inline-block;width:38%;text-align : left; margin : -20px;padding-left : 10px ; padding-right:10px">
                             <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" Text="Yes" Checked="false" /></span>
 <span style="display:inline-block;width:38%;"> <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Checked="false" ID="chk2" Text="No" /></span></span></asp:Label>
```

So, My form will be sumbitted using jquery and it will find all the elements that i have mentioned below.

```
$this.find('.required :input, .required select').each(function () {

                var $input = $(this),
                fieldValue = $.trim($input.val()),
    labelText = $input.closest('label').text().replace(o.removeLabelChar, ''),
                        errorMsg = '';
```

So, this find method method will looks for all the input elements. But unfortunately i am not able to find my checkbox. Kindly proivde some solutions.

Comment: Gah, edited it right before I saved

Comment: Can we see the html after it has been emitted to the browser?

Comment: Why so many inline styles? Don't you know how to use classes and external style sheets?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your checkbox isn't nested into any 'input' control or any 'select' control. That is why your code cannot find it.
2. To access your checkbox use `$('label span input[type="checkbox"]')`

PS: Dude, do something with your code, it looks... very bad.